# how while loop is incremented in feof( ) to read in C

Tags: c, file

I have the following code.

```
 while( !feof(fp1) && !feof( fp2)
 {
    fscanf(fp1, "%s", name);
    fscanf( fp2, "%s", usn);
    fprintf(fp3, "%s%s\n", name, usn);
 }
```

In this i understand that feof flag will be set when EOF is read. But how does it read string after another in the file?
I have not included any such code in the loop. Still it reads all the strings till the end in both the files and writes to fp3. 
Please explain

Comment: You may want to read up on fscanf().  It reads the next string in input and stops at whitespace.

Comment: By the way - this is a very unsafe way to read because fscanf can easily write beyond the size of the output variable's space.

Comment: "Still it reads all the strings till the end in both the files and writes to fp3." No, it doesn' *quite* do that. [Demo](http://ideone.com/LjTZqm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the results of `fscanf()` for EOF.

`feof()` indicates `EOF` happened on the *previous* IO operation.

```
 while ((fscanf(fp1, "%s", name) != EOF) && (fscanf( fp2, "%s", usn) != EOF)) {
   fprintf(fp3, "%s%s\n", name, usn);
}
```

---

Detail:

"feof flag will be set when EOF is read" is mis-leading.  EOF is not something that is read.  It is a condition that occurs when input is attempted but fails because there is no more data possible.  In C, code does not know if the next `char` of input is available before it tries to read it.  Code needs to to try to read and fail - then the EOF condition is set.

Code like `fscanf(fp1, "%s", name);` does not check the return value of `fscanf()`.  This is hazardous as code is not assured that anything was read into `name`.  Certainty that `scanf()` succeeded (or not) is obtain by checking the return value.

"how does it read string after another in the file? ..." can only be guessed as posted code is faulty. `while( !feof(fp1) && !feof( fp2) {` is *at least* missing a `)`.  As to what the true code OP has is then guess-work.

Assuming `while( !feof(fp1) && !feof( fp2)) {`, the code loops repeatedly reading a string of non-white-space characters from each file.   It continues *once too often* as the last time it reads, `fp1` and/or `fp2` reach their EOF condition and so the last `printf()` likely contains a repeat of the previously read `name` and/or `usn`.

OP has not show declaration of `name,usn`.  Quite possible, either of these are insufficient for the data read and buffers have over-flowed resulting in undefined behavior.  @ash

Answer (score 0):

Close the parenthesis.. `while( !feof(fp1) && !feof( fp2) )`

And, you did not include any code to read the strings from files and write into another file?? But I can see `fscanf()` and `fprintf()`!